# not able to restart apache server AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine

Tags: permissions, apache2, amazon-ec2, https, aws

I am working on AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine. I am not able to restart my apache server.
following is the error is showing when i use `Listen 80` in `ports.conf`

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

> $ service apache2 restart  * Restarting web server apache2
>   (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   [::]:80 (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. The Apache error
>   log may have more information.

and when I go with `Listen 8080`

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

> $ service apache2 restart  * Restarting web server apache2
>   (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   [::]:443 (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address 0.0.0.0:443 no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. The Apache error
>   log may have more information.

**This all happen when I go for SSL.**
logs are empty. no error found in logs (`/var/log/apache2`)

Comment: Are you running the restart as superuser (i.e. `sudo service apache2 restart`)?  If not, you need to - you can't bind to ports under 1024 without superuser.  Also, edit your question and include the output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443`

Comment: I tried with sudo su too. but face same

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443`

Comment: sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443 run fine.

Comment: same error when run restart command after `netstat -tulpn | grep 443 run`

Comment: apache restarted but site is not running

Comment: Read my answer.  I explain one of the potential reasons for problems here, and a potential resolution.

Comment: Also, check `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and see if there's any output for port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Permission Denied" indicates that you don't have permissions to bind to a port.

This can happen for several reasons, including:

1. Not using `sudo` or superuser powers when restarting Apache
2. Something else is already listening on port 80 or 443.

Firstly, for Port 80, check this: `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`. This will list all processes binding to port 80 and their names on the rightmost column.

For port 443, use this, and the same general thing should be kept in mind:  `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443`.

---

Note, though, that the port 443 problem may be related to issues I've observed.

There is also an issue on 14.04 that I've personally observed, which is that listening with the `ssl_module` and `mod_gnutls` will cause this problem too (discovered when configuring a service).  You will need to comment out one or the other in `ports.conf` and use one or the other rather than both.  (Or, have `mod_gnutls` listen on a different port, or `mod_ssl` listen on a different port)